# How to do I prevent my loop from running one extra time?

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

I'm running a while loop to read from an input file and write to an output file. The program appears to work perfectly except the final line is read twice. I believe this code is supposed to loop until the file has nothing left to be read and closes.

```
while (my_input_file) {
my_output_file << getStudentID() << "  " << studentScores() << " ";
totalScore();
calculatePercentage();
calculateGrade();
}
```

Comment: I don't see where you are reading, but I believe you've stumbled over a variant of [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Comment: Unfortunately there's not enough here to see exactly what's wrong. We need more context. Could you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58495355/edit) and post a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `istream` doesn't know it has reached the end of the file until *after* it tried to read past the end of the file. If you have only read exactly the contents of the file, the `istream` still thinks that it's good to go, which means you need to insert `istream::fail` checks after trying to read something from the file.